# Why does tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_director not take all images?

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I have a directory with 12140 png images all created with the same algorithm. They are all around 100kB.
However, when I use

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  PATH,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(800, 720),
  batch_size=16)
```

It returns

> Found 37 files belonging to 1 classes.
> Using 30 files for training.

I want to train a convolutional autoencoder, so I don't need labels. All the images are in the same directory. There are no subdirectories.

```
len(glob(PATH+'/*png'))
> 12140
```

At least I would expect the function to find all images. What can go wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems images have to be in a sub-directory. When I use the parent directory of `PATH` the images are found.